# Redeploying a war file with a single modified file in glassfish server

Tags: deployment, glassfish

I have a deployed application in glassfish web server V2. But every time a modification is made in project, even in a single file, I have to stop the server and redeploy the whole war file. Now I am wondering if there is a feature in the app server to just modify the deployed application with the changes made live.

Answer (score 0):

just *redeploy* with `force=true`.